# Will my wood platform support my generator?

Tags: deck, generator

I built a wood platform out of pressure treated lumber 6ft X 4ft 2x6 with beams every 16 inches and 2x6 deck.  It is bolted into the house 2x10 on the 6 ft rear wall and carriage bolted to an existing deck on one 4ft side.  It is carriage bolted to 4 4x4's that extend to a concrete driveway.

The generator weighs a total of 500 lb.  I need to compute the weight per square inch that the platform will support.

Comment: What's the question? It sounds like you've already built the platform.

Comment: for a 500 lb generator?  You've got more than ample support.

Comment: Did you try jumping on it? I'm pretty sure jumping on it is the standard DIY live load test. Jumping then wiggling and/or gyrating tests live loads in multiple directions.  Getting all the people within earshot to stand on it, is the standard DIY dead load test.

Comment: 2X6 with a 2X deck will hold 600 pounds per square foot easily, especially if it is resting on a concrete slab.

Comment: I'm picturing something [like this](http://i.imgur.com/Ake03.png), is that correct?

Comment: The generator does not uniformly load the platform, so I don't see what a psi rating will tell you. But exterior decks need to support 60 psf, so that may be the controlling factor. The weakest link is probably the bolts, which is highly dependent on the detailing, so no one can say for sure without more information. But it sounds adequate.

Answer (score 1):

As long as everything is joined and fastened properly a 6'x4' platform framed and decked with 2x6 will hold much more than a 500 lbs generator.

Though I don't think I'd count a driveway as a proper footing for your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a terrible and dangerous idea to mount it on a wood deck. The muffler is within six to 8 inches of base and it will, under the wrong circumstances, set the deck on fire. Check the install manual. It will require fireproof base, preferably concrete.

Answer (score -1):

Generators should not be mounted on a wood deck. Check the installation manual.

Comment: You could improve your answer by explaining why

Comment: This depends on the footings of the deck, materials and so on.   There is nothing innately wrong with mounting a generator on a wood deck.